# How to enable Username resolution in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, domain, username

Let's say you want to send an Email to `Bob Dilan`. In Outlook 2007, if you already sent a mail to `Bob Dilan` in the past, you could just type `dilab`, if `dilab` is his actual username on the domain. In Outlook 2010, it doesn't seem to work anymore. I still can use Outlook 2007 on another computer, and it still works.

Is it a client-side setting? If so, how do I change that?

Is it an exchange-side setting? If so, can I get some information about that feature?

Thanks

Comment: It works fine for me but you do have to send an email first for it to appear in the instant results.